# Is there an implicit < inheritdoc />?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, comments, inheritdoc

In Visual Studio I noticed that when i hover a method, it acts like there is an < inheritdoc />, when there isn't.

[Visual example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNzuC.png)

Why and from where is that? Because of Visual Studio?

Also, should I still add the < inheritdoc /> or leave it then, what do you think?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Looks like this was added when `<inheritdoc/>` was first added to VS 2 years ago in [dotnet/roslyn#36028](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/pull/36028) (it was supported by various documentation generators before then, but not by VS itself). Also see [dotnet/csharplang#313](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/313) and [dotnet/roslyn#56463](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/56463)

Comment: @canton7 Thank you, your provided links (especially the 3th) answered my question.